# Get each text value with each button click on a LongListselector in windows phone 8

Tags: .net, json, windows-phone-8

I need to know how can i get each text value when i press on a user list , in that sample when i press follow i need to get text details of textblock. How can i do that in Code behind?

i want to click to button and i see each textvalue in the 'f'

```
       <phone:LongListSelector Name="productx"  Margin="0,70,0,235" LayoutMode="List"  Background="#FFF9F9F9" BorderBrush="#FFE6E6E6" Foreground="#FF171717" FontSize="20"                   
          >
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>


                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">

                        <TextBlock  x:Name="f" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Text="{Binding name}" FontStyle="Italic" />

                        <Button x:Name="btn_Parse2" Click="btn_Parse2_Click" Content="Folowla!" Tag="{Binding name}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150" Background="#FF0079F1" Foreground="#FFE6E6E6" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Height="Auto"/>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Comment: i have tried but it doesnt work, message says: f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have the same value on the Tag property of the Button that the one displayed by the TextBlock. You can retrieve this property by using the *sender* argument of the Click event handler:

```
private void btn_Parse2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   string text = (string)((Button)sender).Tag;
}
```

Comment: okay how can i change button background color?             ((Button)sender).Background = ;

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Tap" event instead of the Click event. Tap covers "Click" as well.

The tap event signature is as followed:
event(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)

sender is of type "Button" and contains all properties of your button. You may access the Tag property which you bound to the same value as the TextBlock Text. Or you navigate through the visial tree (Button Parent) to access the TextBlock within the parent Stackpanel.
This way you can also change the Text Content.

Ideally you only need to change the value in the underlying view model instance and the TextBlock is adjusted automatically. But your code does not seem to make use of the MVVM concept. 
See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286405(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286405%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for more details about this concept.

Comment: how can i get a stackpanel child value with button click

Comment: Cast the sender to a Button object. Then you can access the Stackpanel with the "Parent" Property of the Button. Cast this to the Stackpanel type and you have access to "Children" Property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children.aspx